# the elements of Cantor's discontinuum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cantor-set

Let $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ the sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, given by $A_0 := \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}[2k, 2k + 1]$ und $A_n := \frac{1}{3}A_{n-1}$ for $n ≥ 1$.

Also, we define

$$ A := \bigcap_{n=0}^\infty A_n, \,C:= A \cap [0, 1]$$

We call $C$ Cantor's discontinuum.

Given this definition, I now want to prove that $C$ consists of all the real numbers of the form $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{3^k}$, where $a_k = 0$ or $a_k = 2$.

Thanks in advance! I'm beginning to understand what $C$ actually looks like, but I don't really know how to show this. My idea was to maybe use the three-adic representation of numbers?

Comment: Usually, we call $C$ the Cantor set. My strategy would be to show that for any $x\in \Bbb R$ where $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{3^k}$ such that $a_k\in\{0,2\}$ for all $k$, we have that for any $n\in\Bbb N$, $x\in A_n$. Conversely, you would need to show every number $y\in C$ has such a series expression. This is fairly easy to see visually and it is easy to make a hand-wavy argument. You can make a rigorous argument using a standard Cauchy convergence approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an image of the Cantor set:

[image: Cantor set]

*Image [File:Cantor5.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cantor5.svg) by [User:sarang](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Sarang)*

Imagine, you want to describe a number $x$ of the cantor set uniquely. Here you have to specify at each iteration, whether you have to go to the left or
the right subinterval in order to finally reach $x$:

[image]

Because each number of the cantor set is uniquely defined by a path of the form

$$( \text{left, right, left, left,}\ldots)$$

The numbers of the cantor sets are bijective to $\{\text{left}, \text{right}\}^\mathbb N$ or $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ (0 may mean "go to the left subinterval" and 1 may mean "go to the right interval"). So we see, that the Cantor set has uncountable many objects.

Now take the starting point $s=0$. To reach a final number $x$ of the Cantor set you add $\frac{2}{3^k}$ to go the right subinterval in the $k$-th iteration and you add $0$ to go to the left subinterval:

[image]

This shows that the Cantor set consists of all real numbers with a 3-adic representation only containing 0 and 2.

Okay, this is no rigorous proof, but I think you get the basic idea... ;-)