# Property of Cantor set

Tags: general-topology

How to prove that no segment of the form $\left(\dfrac{3k+1}{3^m}, \dfrac{3k+2}{3^m}\right)$ where $k$ and $m$ are positive integers, has a point in commoin with Cantor set.

How to prove this strictly?

Comment: What is your definition of a Cantor set?

Comment: For the usual construction as $[0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=0}^{3^{m-1}-1} \left(\frac{3k+1}{3^m},\frac{3k+2}{3^m}\right)$, this fact comes directly from definition.

Comment: How to prove formula that you wrote? My definition of Cantor set is such(from Rudin's book): We take $E_0=[0,1]$ and delete segment $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$ and got interval $[0,1/3]\cup [2/3,1]$ and proceed this construction. And we have the sequence of intervals $E_0\supset E_1 \supset E_2 \supset \dots$ and $P=\cap _{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$. We called $P$ a Cantor set. Can you explain you formula?

Comment: Another property of the Cantor set: if the base 3 expansion has a 1 in it, then it is *not* in the Cantor set.   Your interval consists of numbers with a 1 in the $3^{-m-1}$ place.

Comment: If you are using such an English-based definition of the Cantor set, then it is equally obvious that each of those segments of that form are precisely some middle third that got removed. If you want a rigorous proof, you need to provide an equally precise definition of the Cantor set. *lisyarus* gave one.

Comment: I gave my definition of Cantor set. But how to prove the above formula using my above definition? I can't find any link that have precise proof.

Comment: Maybe http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1279517/32951 will help you...

Comment: The place where your definition lacks the requisite rigor is the words "and proceed this construction" in your first comment. What is needed, to make the definition rigorous, is to replace these words by a **definition by induction**, also known as **recursive definition**.  Once you have done that, then you can use the definition by induction to give a rigorous proof by induction, proving that the deleted intervals all have the format in your question.

Comment: Section 18 of https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs173/sp2011/lectures/induction.pdf explains the relation between recursive definitions and proofs by induction.